# Filtering image by ID number in Google Earth Engine JavaScript API

Tags: google-earth-engine, geojson, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter

I have a landsat image collection. I want to select third and fourth image using the features ID (index number) not using the image metadata.

How it can be achieved?

[image]

On console we see features as a GeoJSON. I want to select any image by feature ID like

```
features.4; // 4th image
```

If it's a list

```
features[4];
```

Comment: Please add your code as text, not picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the ImageCollection into a `ee.List` and then access the desired images using the index numbers. The only argument you need to indicate in the `.toList()` method is the maximum number of elements to fetch, which you can set as the size of the ImageCollection.

```
myCollection = myCollection.toList(myCollection.size());

myCollection.get(4);
```